# java - Array index is out of bounds

Tags: java

Why does this code show the error message java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2146737495!!
I think that the size of array is sufficient enough.

```
class Main {
static int[] ara = new int[1000010];


public static void seive(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        ara[i] = 0;
    ara[1] = 1;

    for(int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i ++)
    {
        if(ara[i] == 0)
        {
            for(int j = i * i; j <= 1000000; j += i)
                ara[j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    seive();
}
```

}

Comment: `int a= 1000000;
int b= a*a;
System.out.println(b);` look at the result

Comment: I added some underscores to make the numbers easier to grasp. And another note: You are receiving the downvotes because SO should not be a place where you drop your code and others solve your problem.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve. The question is too vague, to be honest :)

Comment: I was trying to find the reason why i was getting array out of index exception. Now i found the reason. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing: j = i * i
When I log the code with this piece:

```
for(int j = i * i; j <= 1000000; j += i)
{
     System.out.println("i: " + i + " -j: " + j);
     ara[j] = 1;
}
```

I ge this output:

```
i: 997 -j: 997000
i: 997 -j: 997997
i: 997 -j: 998994
i: 997 -j: 999991
i: 46349 -j: -2146737495
```

The j = i * i (which will be -2146737495) throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays have size limited first by memory and after by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

You are passing the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in the array position.

But value `-2146737495` is negative, **why???**.

Because `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE`